# "Correct" way to write log output from a background (Resque) job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, resque

Resque jobs are just plain old ruby objects.  I can use `puts` calls inside them to produce output into the console, or I can instantiate a standard Ruby `Logger` class with `STDOUT` and use that.

But is there a correct approach to logging in Rails, from places that aren't controllers or models?  I see `Rails.logger` returns a `BufferedLogger`, but when I call `info` or `warn` etc on it, nothing happens.  If I call `flush` on it, it just returns an empty array and nothing is output.

What's the convention here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure that there is a convention.  I had a pretty ugly logging system up until just recently.  Now I use [lumber](https://github.com/wr0ngway/lumber) to integrate [log4r](http://log4r.rubyforge.org/) with Rails.  That really made logging much nicer because I now have named loggers (e.g., logger matches the class name -- great for filtering output) and I can control log levels on a per-logger (i.e., per-class) basis.

There's also a [GELF adapter](https://github.com/wr0ngway/log4r-gelf) for log4r if you want to use graylog2 to aggregate your logs.